# Why is $n_{n^2-1}$ the smallest graph that clearly shows the structure of multiplication by $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mathematics-education, visualization

Initially, I wanted to ask this question as a puzzle.

> 1. Consider a regular $m$-gon. Let $0$ be the lower corner and count the corners clockwise.
> 2. Let $n_m$ be the multiplication-by-$n$-graph of $m$ for $n < m$ by drawing an arrow from every corner $a$ to the corner $a\cdot
>     n\operatorname{mod}m$. 
>    <sub>These are the eight relevant
>      multiplication-by-$n$-graphs of $10$ as (hopefully) intelligible to every school
>      kid:</sub> [image]
> 3. For fixed $n$, in the limit $m \rightarrow \infty$ the graph $n_m$ will **somehow** display $n-1$ cusps. 
>    <sub>E.g. $10_{517}$:</sub>
>    [image]
> 4. What is the smallest graph $n_m$ that **undeniably** displays $n-1$ cusps?

You may think hard about this (or not), but the (probably right) answer can be found easily by simulation: Just draw the graphs

[image]
 and you will find that the graph with $m = n^2-1$

[image]

yields this smallest graph.

Be promised: It's the same for arbitrary $n$ instead of $10$:

[image]

Even for smaller $n$ than $10$:

[image]

My question is:

> **Why** is this so?

I'm looking for strong algebraic and/or arithmetic arguments. I have no idea.

Comment: Why stop at the smallest $m$? For various small values of $n$, can you tell us which are the *first few* $m$ for which you would say that your graph $n_m$ "undeniably" displays $n-1$ cusps?

Comment: You may get an "idea" (see it) earlier, but how to make this precise? I know that my idea of  "undeniably" may be discussion-worthy. But I have an "idea" (see) why and how it is "outstanding".

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: BTW: The question is not about *various small* values of $n$, but about *arbitrarily large* values.

Comment: So I don't quite understand what counts at undeniably displaying $n-1$ cusps but, as (hopefully) intelligible to every school kid, $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$, so you have $n-1$ group linked by two-way edges (reflecting the fact that $n^2$ is $1$), which produces a nice figure as in your pictures. For smaller values, there is a perturbation related to the fact that either $n^2$ is not $1$ which destroys somewhat the symmetry or there are not enough groups (or both). To be more mathematically precise, I would need to be able to give a mathematical content to "undeniably displaying cusps".

Comment: @Olivier: For now I have nothing more to say than that $n_{n^2−1}$ is the smallest graph that reveals the cuspiness with minimal clutter.

Comment: @Olivier: There is something - obvious - what the graphs $10_{99}$, $11_{120}$, $12_{143}$, $13_{168}$ have in common - minimal clutter.

Comment: @Olivier: I don't understand immediately what $n^2-1 = (n+1)(n-1)$ has to do with my question. Something obvious?

Comment: @Olivier: To be honest: "undeniably displaying cusps" has no definite mathematical content - but some undeniable "perceptual" content  - making a gap I'd like to bridge.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen:  For **any** $n>4$ I would say that $n_{n^2-1}$ is the smallest graph that "undeniably" displays cusps. (See my new pictures above.)

Comment: To the close voter: I cannot understand that  my question is considered to be unclear (supposing one accepts my admittedly somehow unclear - but strongly supported by examples  - definition of "undeniably displaying cusps").

Comment: Because $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$, multiplication by $n$ modulo $n^2-1$ is an involution that sends the $n+1$ terms $0,2,\cdots,n$ each to one of the $n-1$ another $n$-ade (decade for $n=10$). This it seems to me, entirely explains the nice (but trivially simple) geometric design observed.

Comment: Let me add that this is very easy to see for the smallish number you displayed (for instance for $5\leq m\leq 8$): one sees clearly the involutive aspect and the fact that each element of the smallest group of $n+1$ terms is sent to a different group, hence the nice display with $n-1$ cusps.

Comment: @HansStricker, surely [you](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315305/why-is-n-n2-1-the-smallest-graph-that-clearly-shows-the-structure-of-multip#comment786631_315305) have explained the close vote yourself?  You say that the question is not unclear if one accepts an unclear premise, but I think that a question that can only be phrased using the undefined term 'undeniably' is not yet a precise mathematical question.

Comment: Please consider that  **your** "seeing clearly" isn't necessarily **my** "seeing clearly" - and vice versa.

Comment: @HansStricker I do understand that your question is about the smallest $m$ for every $n$ and not simply small values of $n$, but if we try to find the pattern of $m$'s for various small values of $n$ it can help guess why this pattern should start at $n^2-1$; and it can also help others understand what your "seeing clearly" is. This is why I suggested this. But if you are somehow opposed to even considering larger $m$'s, hey, it's your question, not mine.

Comment: If your "seeing clearly" isn't my "seeing clearly", Hans, then doesn't that justify a vote to close the question as "primarily opinion-based"? Mind you, I'm not voting to close it, but I do think Olivier's comment about involutions explains what's going on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I disagree: Seeing (or not) clearly isn't a matter of opinion but of ability.

Comment: OK, then, I guess I misinterpreted your "seeing clearly" comment, Hans. May I suggest that when there's a long stream of comments involving several people, then a comment intended to engage with a specific previous comment should make it clear which comment it is intended to engage with (for example, by explicitly naming the author of that comment)? Anyway, if what you were trying to convey was that Olivier was more able than your good self to see what was going on in your question, maybe you could say that less elliptically. I'd like to see @Olivier expand his/her comments to an answer.

Comment: "I cannot understand that my question is considered to be unclear (supposing one accepts my admittedly somehow unclear - but strongly supported by examples - definition of "undeniably displaying cusps")" That's precisely how one can consider your question unclear: by finding it hinges on a too-unclear definition.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You are right, thanks for the hint. And yes, I'd like to see Olivier's comment as an answer, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the request of Gerry Myerson, here is what I understand.

As $n^2=1$ modulo $n^2-1$, the multiplication by $n$ graph on $m=n^2-1$ vertices as defined in the question is formed

1) First, of isolated points which satisfy $nx=x$, or equivalently $(n+1)|x$, of which there are $n-1$. These are the $n-1$ initial point of each "cusps" (a "cusp" is a group of $n+1$ consecutive points on the circle starting with a point congruent to 0 modulo $n+1$).

2) Second, of bi-directional edges relating a pair of points. Now, if $x=y+k(n+1)$ with $0\leq y\leq n$, then $nx=ny+k+kn=ny+k(n+1)=-y+(k+y)(n+1)$ so each point in the $n+1$ terms are linked to a different group.

This entirely explains the nice display when $m=n^2-1$. If $m<n^2-1$, then $(n-1)(n+1)>m$, so there can be no periodicity of the form above.

Now, how about the assertion that when $m$ is large with respect to $n$, we do see $n-1$ "cusps"? The slopes of two consecutive edges (corresponding to $nx$ and $n(x+1)$) are increasing. Visually, if you incrementally increase slopes of lines, this draws the convex envelope of a cusp (people who know more than me about geometry, that is to say people who know anything at all, will tell us the equation of the cusp drawn in this way). Whence the cusps. When will the cusps be dark (almost vertical slope)? When the edges are close to diameters. And when will that be? When $nx$ is close to $x+m/2$. If that is the case, then $n(x+m/(n-1))$ will also be close to $x+m/(n-1)+m/2$. So we see $n-1$ maximally dark cusps (and likewise one can count the relatively darker cusps by cutting the circle in 3, 4 etc. and translate in terms of congruences).

Putting everything together, if $m$ is large, we see $n-1$ dark cusps, if $m=(n-1)(n+1)$ we see $n-1$ grouping shuffled by multiplication by $n$ and this periodicity can not occurred if $m<(n-1)(n+1)$. So yes, $n^2-1$ is the first instance in which the ultimate pattern unambiguously appear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to understand my question, and thanks for the answer which is as definite as I could hope for.

Comment: @HansStricker What I'd like to know is how you drew the pictures (and if that is not too much to ask, if you could send me a couple of the large ones as large png?).

Comment: If you send me an email to stricker@syspedia.de, I'll send you a link.